# React.memo performance is worse than with React.PureComponent

Tags: reactjs

Some time ago I did refactoring of cell renderers components to achieve performance gain (I have a huge table). I did refactoring from functional stateless components to `PureComponent`. E.g.:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class SomeCell extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { pizzaOrder } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        {pizzaOrder.name}
        <br />
        {pizzaOrder.price}
      </>
    );
  }
}

SomeCell .propTypes = {
  pizzaOrder: PropTypes.object,
};

export default SomeCell ;
```

Now I saw that `React.memo` was released so I updated to `react@16.6.0` and `react-dom@16.6.0` (from `16.5.2`) and refactored from `PureComponent` to `React.memo` with an expectation that it would be even faster (no lifecycle methods called, function smaller than class in memory etc...):

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const SomeCell = React.memo(function({ pizzaOrder }) {
  return (
    <>
        {pizzaOrder.name}
        <br />
        {pizzaOrder.price}
    </>
  );
});

SomeCell .propTypes = {
  pizzaOrder: PropTypes.object,
};

export default SomeCell;
```

And to my surprise, performance went significantly down.

Do you have any idea what could be the issue with it?

Profile data in prod mode (no addons in chrome) show that there's much more scripting happening then before with `PureComponent` (scripting time for my case went from 0.5s to 3.8sek).

**EDIT: after some investigation, it seems that it is not an issue with React.memo but with a new version of React. I've reverted cell renderers to PureComponent and left new react@16.6.0 version and the result (significantly slower performance) is still present**

Comment: can you report it as an issue into their github?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested by @skyboyer an issue was created in [React Repository](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13987).

**Summary of the issue (2018-11-11):**

- The issue was not related to React itself but to an `uglify-es` (buggy) optimization.
- `uglify-es` is inlining code (that should not be inlined).
- `uglify-es` is not actively maintained anymore.
- The proposed solution is to use `terser` as a replacement.
- If you are using `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` or Webpack 4.x.x (that uses `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` by default), you should change the minifier option in [webpack configuration](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimization-minimizer) like this:

  ```js
  const TerserWebpackPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

  module.exports = {
    //...
    optimization: {
      minimizer: [
        new TerserWebpackPlugin({ /* your config */ })
      ]
    }
  };
  ```

Comment: Is this still an issue or should we switch to Terser?

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR:

> upgrade webpack to version 4.26

as they switched to [terser](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin) as the default minimizer.

**Background:**

- `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` < v1.0 used the minifier `uglify-js`
- however `uglify-js` does not support ES6, which resulted in a fork   called `uglify-es` that was developed in the `uglify-js` repository,   but under the `harmony` branch
- `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` v1.x switched to `uglify-es` for ES6 support
- however `uglify-es` stopped being maintained:   mishoo/UglifyJS2#3156 (comment)
- which led to a fork called `terser` that has incorporated all of   the unmerged PRs and will be where all new development occurs:   https://github.com/fabiosantoscode/terser
- `terser-webpack-plugin` was created, which is the `terser` equivalent   of `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin`:   https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin
- `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` v2.x will be switching back to `uglify-js`,   so any project that needs to support ES6 now needs to switch to   `terser-webpack-plugin`.

**Reference:** [webpack/commit](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/commit/311a7285d36b38bada46102967c431e93ff48a89)